# Spring Data: how to create a repository query that only returns the rows that have greater than 5 in @ManyToMany.size() property

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

Consider the following Entity

```
@Entity
public class Team {

    private String title;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "teams")
    @OrderBy("firstName ASC")
    private Set<User> users = new HashSet<>();
}
```

I want to create a repository findBy query, that returns all entries of team, with a users.count() above 5.

SQL I'm expecting is:

```
SELECT t.title, count(*) as total_users FROM team t 
LEFT JOIN team_users tu on t.id=tu.team_id  
GROUP BY t.id HAVING total_users > 5;
```

From what I researched there is a few ways to do this, but I cant figure out any of them.

1. JpaSpecificationExecutor
2. @Query / NativeQuery
3. NamedNativeQuery

Answer (score 0):

Take `JpaSpecificationExecutor` as an example
You need your repository interface to implement it
In general, your repository should also be an interface

The `JpaSpecificationExecutor` interface then provides several methods, and we'll use `findAll` as an example

```
Specification<DemoEntity> sp = (root, query, cb) -> {
        // where begin
        Predicate fp = cb.conjunction();
        // xxx = 'some value'
        Predicate p1 = cb.equal(root.get("xxx").as(String.class), "some Value");
        // Add to the where
        fp = cb.and(fp, p1);
        Predicate gt = cb.gt(root.get("yyy").as(Integer.class), 5);
        // Finally
        return query.where(fp).groupBy(root.get("xxx")).having(gt).getRestriction();

};
```